# Adding another data series in plot

Tags: javascript, json, flot

I currently have a PHP file which returns:

`[[38,38],[38,113],[38,188],[38,263],[38,338],[38,413],[38,488],[113,38],[113,113],[113,188],[113,263],[113,338],[113,413],[113,488],[188,38],[188,113],[188,188],[188,263],[188,338],[188,413],[188,488],[263,38],[263,113],[263,188],[263,263],[263,338],[263,413],[263,488],[338,38],[338,113],[338,188],[338,263],[338,338],[338,413],[338,488],[413,38],[413,113],[413,188],[413,263],[413,338],[413,413],[413,488],[488,38],[488,113],[488,188],[488,263],[488,338],[488,413],[488,488],[75,75],[75,150],[75,225],[75,300],[75,375],[75,450],[150,75],[150,150],[150,225],[150,300],[150,375],[150,450],[225,75],[225,150],[225,225],[225,300],[225,375],[225,450],[300,75],[300,150],[300,225],[300,300],[300,375],[300,450],[375,75],[375,150],[375,225],[375,300],[375,375],[375,450],[450,75],[450,150],[450,225],[450,300],[450,375],[450,450]]`

I use this in an AJAX call like

```js
$.ajax({
    url:'fetcher/allseedpositions.php',
    async: false,
    success:function(datasets){
        seedPos = jQuery.parseJSON(datasets);
        allNodePos = $.plot($("#allnodepositions"),[ seedPos ],optionsSeed);        
    }
})
```

to plot but now I want another series to be plotted also along with this, with different symbol.
I am confused on using JSON and I cannot add more properties.

Comment: You've asked about how to generate the JSON but you haven't included the code with generates your JSON...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create a new array and push the next data set for display. http://jsfiddle.net/fZbVL/

```
var dataSet1 = [ 
          [1,5],[4,7]
];

var dataSet2 = [
[1,2],[3,4]
];

var dataSet3 = [
[1,4],[4,6]
]



var data = []
data.push(dataSet1);
data.push(dataSet2);
data.push(dataSet3);

$.plot($("#placeholder"),
      data);
```